# Proper Semantic-UI / Bower / Rails 4 configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, bower, semantic-ui

I'm struggling to properly install and configure Semantic-UI using bower in my Rails 4 app.
Until now, here's what I've done:

Gemfile:

```
gem "less-rails"
gem "therubyracer"
```

.bowerrc file:

```
{
  "directory": "vendor/assets/components"
}
```

bower.json:

```
{
"name": "app",
"version": "0.0.0",
"homepage": "myapp.com",
"private": true,
"ignore": [
 "**/.*",
 "node_modules",
 "bower_components",
 "vendor/assets/components",
 "test",
 "tests"
],
"dependencies": {
  "semantic-ui": "~1.12.2"
 }
}
```

After bower install, semantic UI gets properly pulled into my /vendor/assets/components folder

Now, I'd like to take advantage of semantic's theming properties, without of course editing what's currently loaded by bower.

I've added the following in semantic.css.less, itself being required in application.css

```
@import "semantic-ui/src/semantic";
```

The issue now: semantic lib seems to be properly fetched in the proper folder, as I get the following error:

> 'site//globals/site.variables' wasn't found
>   Ok I understand that.

But how do I **use custom configuration files** with the default assets installed by bower without touching these ?
How can I properly create the required configuration files (theme.config / site.variables / site.overrides), out of my /vendor/assets/components folder, and still properly assigning the SASS variables required for the lib to compile ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a gander at [less-rails-semantic-ui](https://github.com/maxd/less-rails-semantic_ui), this is what I ended up going for my new rails project. It properly adds all the override files in vendor/assets!

Comment: Like the idea of not having ugly tweaks around the app. Going to give this gem a shot. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using less source files without npm (which includes an installer), you will need to manually create theme.config from theme.config.example and site/ from _site/ this is to avoid upstream changes affecting your local ui.
https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/tree/master/src#config-files

PS: from the owner answer, source:
https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/2239